# Sublime Text - Set project type as Django

Tags: django, sublimetext2, sublimetext

A little confused. Trying to create a Django project in Sublime Text.

I have followed this  [netuts guide](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-project-bliss/)
So I have added a folder and set a project as django.sublime-project

I installed Djaniero plugin. So my question is how do I now turn this into a django project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Djaniero is just a collection of snippets for Django.

If you're looking for a plugin that will give you autocompletion for Python, etc, take a look at [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) or [SublimeRope](https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimeRope).

Comment: I think I realised what is supposed to happen I am supposed to get the command line and do django-admin.py startmyproject. And then open sublime and assign that folder to a sublime project. My bad I was expecting sublime to do this.

Comment: No worries. I'm still adjusting to Sublime Text 2 myself coming from PyCharm.

Comment: I have both py charm and sublime installed trying them.  Why did you choose sublime over pycharm

Comment: I really love PyCharm, but I found it to be a little slow and the interface a bit clunky. I like Sublime because it's very, very fast. The interface is very attractive and I can fine-tune plugins to my liking. SublimeRope and SublimeLinter are probably the most useful plugins for me.